# In Oracle SQL , is there a way to count the totals in previous rows ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query where I need to make counts of items in different categories. The issue is that we have to make a count of the subcounts :

[image]

So what I would like to do , is to count the totals for Barbara as a new column.

But when we try to count them via a WITH query , it's not working because there is some overlap ( there can be different requisitions within one requisition-header) .

I know that in SQL, we can count previous columns in a SELECT clause , like this :

```
SELECT x1, x2, x3, x2 + x3 AS "x2 + x3"
```

So i was wondreing if I can do something like this but for the previous rows?

Any tips appreciated , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select fullname,
       sum(case when category = 'NONBOM' then count else 0 end) as nonbom,
       sum(case when category = 'BOM' then count else 0 end) as bom,
       sum(case when category = 'CAPITAL' then count else 0 end) as captital,
       SUM(count) as total
from table t
group by fullname;
```